# Convert .xls file to xml using php

Tags: php, mysql, xml, excel

I need to implement a functionality where a user can upload an Excel file, that is, .xls file and i need to write a function that will read that file and then save the values in a table, compare them to values in another table and then print some kind of billing quotation. 
From what I have read, it seems that the best way to do that is to first convert that file to an xml file and then write a function to parse that xml file.
I want to know, is it possible to write a function in php that will convert an xls file to xml. Assuming that the users will save and upload the file as xls.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are your reasons for converting to XML as an intermediary step?  If you're not storing the XML, why not process the data directly from XLS to a data structure you'll use for processing?

Comment: I have read it somewhere that the easiest way to manipulate the data in an excel file is to first convert it to xml. Can you tell me where should I start if i want to process the data directly from an xls file?

Answer (score 2):

i often let admin users upload a csv file they exported from an xcel file, its much simpler to parse through using http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: Totally, Get the user to upload a CSV file. They can save as CSV from within Excel.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search for "PHP excel parser" turns up [PHP Excel Reader](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/), for an open source library to use for reading data from `.xls` files.  There may be others that suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks!Do you think it is tough to write my own function to read an excel file using PHP?

Comment: As far as I know xls files are in a binary format, so it could be very difficult to create your own file parser instead of using an existing one.  Since it's open source software, they have probably found and fixed many bugs that you will run into on your own as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have been successfully using the 'ABC Excel Parser Pro' from Zakkis.

This allows converting from a XLS file directly into a MySQL table.

A few notes on limitations:

- column count must match exactly to  database columns
- Excel 2007 format (xlsx) are not supported